# Plotting multiple Figures with Plot.ly

Tags: python, plotly

I have a plot that graphs multiple datasets against time, over several different generations. A slider controls the generation. [image: Here's a gif that hopefully illustrates what I mean.] The way I'm accomplishing this right now is by making (Number of Generations * Number of Lines) scatter plots in a list that I pass in to plotly.offline.plot. This makes creating the generation slider pretty difficult and full of annoying bugs (like the legend changing order for each generation).

My question is this: **Is there some way I can group multiple scatter plots (like with a Figure) and pass in a list of those groups in to plotly.offline.plot?**

Comment: Hi, it's always better share part of your code.